# execute an android database query with a button

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a button the will execute the search query each time it is hit. The query will take 5 random entries from the database and display them in a listview.

```
public abstract class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {

    private Cursor schedule;
    private MyDatabase db;
    ListView listView;
    Button b1 =(Button) findViewById(android.R.id.button1);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db = new MyDatabase(this);
        schedule = db.getSchedule();

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
                listView.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                        MainActivity.this, 
                        R.layout.row,  
                        schedule,                   
                        new String[] {"fName", "Calories", "Protein", "Carbs" },  
                        new int[] { R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3, R.id.textView4 },   
                        0));
            }
        });
    }
```

Catlog:

```
12-03 00:22:51.013: D/dalvikvm(2900): newInstance failed: p0 i0 [0 a1
12-03 00:22:51.013: D/AndroidRuntime(2900): Shutting down VM
12-03 00:22:51.013: W/dalvikvm(2900): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a68ba8)
12-03 00:22:51.113: E/AndroidRuntime(2900): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-03 00:22:51.113: E/AndroidRuntime(2900): Process: com.example.mealplan, PID: 2900
12-03 00:22:51.113: E/AndroidRuntime(2900): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mealplan/com.example.mealplan.MainActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.mealplan.MainActivity
12-03 00:22:51.113: E/AndroidRuntime(2900):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
12-03 00:22:51.113: E/AndroidRuntime(2900):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
12-03 00:22:51.113: E/AndroidRuntime(2900):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-03 00:22:51.113: E/AndroidRuntime(2900):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
12-03 00:22:51.113: E/AndroidRuntime(2900):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-03 00:22:51.113: E/AndroidRuntime(2900):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-03 00:22:51.113: E/AndroidRuntime(2900):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
12-03 00:22:51.113: E/AndroidRuntime(2900):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-03 00:22:51.113: E/AndroidRuntime(2900):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-03 00:22:51.113: E/AndroidRuntime(2900):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-03 00:22:51.113: E/AndroidRuntime(2900):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
12-03 00:22:51.113: E/AndroidRuntime(2900):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-03 00:22:51.113: E/AndroidRuntime(2900): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.mealplan.MainActivity
12-03 00:22:51.113: E/AndroidRuntime(2900):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
12-03 00:22:51.113: E/AndroidRuntime(2900):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
12-03 00:22:51.113: E/AndroidRuntime(2900):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
12-03 00:22:51.113: E/AndroidRuntime(2900):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
```

i added a catlog for the problems and inserted the suggestions to show what i have when i get these errors.

Comment: Why did you comment out the button.setOnClickListener code? it looks ok apart from using "button" when your button variable is actually b1.

Comment: ill add the logCat for that code being uncommented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please put the line in your code.
**b1.setonclickListener(this);**

Without write this line how to call onclick listener method of button?

I hope its useful to you.

**Edit:**

Add this line in after setContentView().

**Button b1 =(Button) findViewById(android.R.id.button1);**

Comment: i added that to the onClick(view v), but it crashes. It has something to do with Button b1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1); If i add that line off code even without using it anywhere, the app crashes

Comment: thank you, i had that button b1 above the setContentView() and it was pissed, why does it need to be below it?

Comment: button will be in xml file and that xml file have been set in setcontentview.that why.

Answer (score 0):

change your code like this!

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {

    private Cursor schedule;
    private MyDatabase db;

    //declare the variables of the ListView and Button
    ListView listView;
    Button b1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db = new MyDatabase(this);
        schedule = db.getSchedule();

        //initialize the ListView and Button
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(android.R.id.button1);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                listView.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, 
                        R.layout.row,  
                        schedule,                   
                        new String[] {"fName", "Calories", "Protein", "Carbs" },  
                        new int[] { R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3, R.id.textView4 },   
                        0));
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: i added the setOnClickListener, but i still recieve the same errors, i added a logcat so you could see what I'm getting

Comment: the logcat is not full。“Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.mealplan.MainActivity”。I cant see this exception is occured in which line in your code

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> can't instantiate class com.example.mealplan.MainActivity
> ```

Abstract classes cannot be instantiated. Remove the `abstract` from your class declaration.